# How to hold the value of a variable in excel bar graph?

Tags: excel, graph

[image]

I have a plot in excel bar graph as shown in the image. But I want the Y axis data to be held at it's value until the next discrete sample in X axis .i.e the value of Y axis is 160.8 at X=1, and I want this value to be held until X=2 where the value of Y changes to 2. How do I do this?

Edit 1 - I tried following this tutorial and it worked - https://trumpexcel.com/step-chart-in-excel/

But I had to format the X axis cells to date format. I want the same to work when X axis format is a number.

Comment: What do you mean by discreet x value? Are you looking for an automation solution?

Comment: I just want the value of Y to change when X changes from 1 to 2,3,4,5....etc. In other words, I want a square waveform kind of a figure rather than stick like figure as in the image.

Comment: Not sure what you really mean, but do all the calculations with variables on the sheet and plot the result. Any change of one or more variables will cause the chart to update. Make sure automatic calculation is selected.

Comment: I want a step waveform.  I tried following this tutorial and it worked - https://trumpexcel.com/step-chart-in-excel/  . But I had to format the X axis cells to date format. Is there any way we could do it with number format?